# Why does my Telerik-based application lose its connection to a remote SQL Server after some time?

Tags: c#, sql-server, tcp, telerik

I'm doing support for a C# application, based on Telerik technology and which is connected to a remote SQL Server.

The connection is set up using a connection string, which looks like this:

```
"Data Source=10.131.53.7;Initial Catalog=DB_name;User ID=User;Password=pwd1234"
```

(Don't worry for the weak password: the information is garbled for security reasons).

Everything is working fine, but after some time (±30 minutes), I get an exception, mentioning that the result of a query can't be retrieved as the connection is broken. The exception message mentions the name of the remote server who is not reachable and that name is empty:

> Unable to reach database server on host ''.

I have the impression that there's a communication problem, closing the connection to the SQL Server in such a way that my application now thinks that the name of the SQL Server's name is empty.

Does anybody know how this is possible?

The machine is still reachable using `ping`:

```
Prompt>ping 10.131.53.7

Pinging 10.131.53.7 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.131.53.7: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=123
Reply from 10.131.53.7: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=123
Reply from 10.131.53.7: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=123
Reply from 10.131.53.7: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=123

Ping statistics for 10.131.53.7:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 22ms, Maximum = 29ms, Average = 25ms
```

I believe the communication between my application and the SQL Server is based on TCP, hence the corresponding tag on this question.

For your information, here's the entire exception message:

> 2023-11-17 08:37:53.5162 | ProductClient.Communications.ServerCommunication | Exception during DB data changed event (changes) ---
> Telerik.OpenAccess.Exceptions.DataStoreException: Unable to reach database server on host ''.
> Error Details:Error executing query:
> Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.sql.SQLException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action'1 wrapCloseInAction)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource'1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
> at OpenAccessRuntime.CommandWrapper.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> at Telerik.OpenAccess.Runtime.Logging.LoggingDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> at Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.Adonet2Generic.Impl.CommandImp.ExecuteReader()
> at Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.Adonet2Generic.Impl.PreparedStatementImp.executeQuery(Nullable'1 commandTimeout)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.Adonet2Generic.Impl.PreparedStatementImp.executeQuery(Nullable'1 commandTimeout)
> at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.conn.PooledPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Nullable'1 commandTimeout)
> at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.fetch.FetchResultImp.Execute()
>
> SQL:
> SELECT a.[voa_class] COL1, a.[AlarmId] COL2, ... FROM [Vehicles] WHERE a.[Id] = ?
>
> Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.sql.SQLException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)